# creating custom routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a custom route like:

```
namespace :admin do
  root 'users#index'
  resources :users do
    get 'admin_login' => 'users#admin_login'
  end
end
```

But when I see with `rake routes`:

```
admin_user_admin_login GET    /admin/users/:user_id/admin_login(.:format)          admin/users#admin_login
```

Why **:user_id** is added here?
I just want it without `:user_id`.

Comment: you can simply add `get 'admin_login' => 'users#admin_login', on: :collection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are creating a custom route within the users resource. Rails is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. You would like to show the "admin_login" route for a specified user (that's what you're currently telling rails to do).

Move the:

```
get 'admin_login' => 'users#admin_login'
```

Line of code outside of the resources block and you'll be able to create your custom route.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an `on` option to tell Rails that it works on a collection and not a member resource.  According to the [official Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

> You can leave out the :on option, this will create the same member
>   route except that the resource id value will be available in
>   params[:photo_id] instead of params[:id].

You can also remove the `=> 'users#admin_login'` part as that is the default behavior.

So the solution to your problem is to add `on: :collection` or place it inside a block like

```
namespace :admin do
  root 'users#index'

  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'admin_login'
    end
  end
end
```